# PHP APC exclude folder from caching

Tags: php, caching, apc

I want to exclude one folder for caching with apc. As apc-filter im using...

```
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.filters="-/var/www/mysite/httpdocs/phpmyadmin/.*"
```

My Problem is now, that my filter not works recursivly. APC is still caching subfolders of phpmyadmin. Any ideas how i can use my filter recursivly?

Comment: That should work. You're not doing anything odd like having a symbolic link to that directory? Er, and you have restarted php-fpm, rather than nginx right?

Comment: Yes i restarted php-fpm everytime, after i made changes in apc.ini

Comment: And it's showing up in your phpinfo output with the correct entry for apc.filters ?

Comment: Yes. Php.ini is correct. My problem is just, that it not works recursive. The first level files (php files in phpmyadmin-root folder like index.php o config.inc.php) are excluded. But not the files in subfolders.

Comment: And did you try the matchall regex "-.*phpmyadmin.*" ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you need to do in order to fix this issue

1. Change your virtual host to disable APC for phpmyadmin:

> ```
> Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"
> <Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/">
>       AllowOverride All
>       Options FollowSymlinks
>       Order allow,deny
>       Allow from all
>       php_admin_value open_basedir "/srv/:/tmp/:/usr/share/:/etc/webapps:/usr/share/pear/"
>       php_admin_value apc.enabled 0
> </Directory>
> ```

1. Add the Filter for all the phpmyadmin pages:

> `apc.filter="-/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.*"`

Answer (score 0):

It should just be working. There's a chance that it's not being picked up because of some funkiness with symbolic paths or how the file is being included.

Either way you could just match anything that has phpmyadmin in the filename like:

```
apc.filters = "-.*phpmyadmin.*"
```